# Make a custom UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need to create a custom NavigationBar. in particular i need to have a navBar with these features:

- 80 px height instead 64 (navBar + statusBar);
- with an image that occupies the entire surface (80 px height);
- with a segmented control in the bottom of the navBar.

I tried to search for a tutorial, but i don't find anything...

EDIT:
this partially solve my question [How do I change UINavigationBar height programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857050/how-do-i-change-uinavigationbar-height-programmatically). Is there a way to make func setNavBarToTheView() working global for all navBar of my application?

Comment: Apple provides sample code for this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved creating a view and adding that view to the viewController, just belove the navigationBar